# Creating dataframe based on pixel values in raster stack in R

Tags: r, dataframe, extract, svm

I am preparing a dataset to run a SVM classification. So far, I have a raster stack  which includes a layer (`[6]`) for training

```
> S1
class       : RasterStack 
dimensions  : 3865, 6899, 26664635, 6  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 14.83, 14.83  (x, y)
extent      : 361363.5, 463675.7, 5760647, 5817965  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
names       : Coherence_VV_Stack2.1, Coherence_VV_Stack2.2, Coherence_VV_Stack2.3, Coherence_VV_Stack2.4, Coherence_VV_Stack2.5, Class 
min values  :                     ?,                     ?,                     ?,                     ?,                     ?,     0 
max values  :                     ?,                     ?,                     ?,                     ?,                     ?,     1
```

Where `S1[[6]]` is:

```
> S1[[6]]
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 3865, 6899, 26664635  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 14.83, 14.83  (x, y)
extent      : 361363.5, 463675.7, 5760647, 5817965  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : Class 
values      : 0, 1  (min, max)
```

and `plot(S1[[6])` is:

[image]

I want to create a `dataframe` (to be used later as input for classification) where:

- If pixel value in `S1[[6]]` is `1`, extract the pixel values in the other layers of the `raster stack` and put it in the `dataframe`
- If pixel value in `S1[[6]]` is`0`, do nothing.

Any suggestion on how to proceed? I know the issue can be solved by importing a `shapefile` and use the `extract` function but I want to use this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `raster::calc` for this:

```
# Prepare function for manipulation with pixels
foo <- function(x){
    # NA case
    if (is.na(x[6])){
        return(NA)
    }
    # If layer 6 is 1
    if (x[6] == 1){
        # Return value from different layer (1 and 2 for example)
        return(x[c(1, 2)])
    } else {
        return(NA)
    }
}

# Use calc to loop over each pixel
new_raster <- calc(S1, foo)

# Convert result to data frame
df <- as.data.frame(new_raster)

# Remove empty values
df <- df[complete.cases(df), ]
```

Comment: Same question as for the other alternative. What if I want to extract the values when S1[[6]] is 1 AND 0. Would it be something like S1[[6]]==1&&0 or S1[[6]]==1 && S1[[6]]==0

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
i <- Which(S1[[6]]==1, cells=TRUE)
df <- data.frame(S1[i])
```

If the data set is smallish enough to fit in RAM memory, you could also take a shortcut on the path Istrel's suggested:

```
df <- as.data.frame(S1) 
df <- df[df[ ,6]== 1, ]
```

Comment: what is `cells=TRUE` doing in this example?

Comment: That is in the help file: `?Which`